# MongoDB 2.6 legacy won't start as Windows Service

Tags: mongodb, windows-services

I have a replica set with 3 Windows Server 2008 R2, and I can't get the MongoDB 2.6 Legacy service working in none of them (I had services with MongoDB 2.4 without any problem in these servers).

This is my YAML config file:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: Z:\MongoDB\log\db02.log
    quiet: false
    logAppend: true

net:
    port: 28019

storage:
    dbPath: Z:\MongoDB\data\db02
    directoryPerDB: true
    journal: 
        enabled: true

replication:
    replSetName: rs0
```

**Assumptions:**

- logpath and dbpath exist (and db02.log file).
- I have access to Z drive

---

**Steps:**

**1. Run command:**

*mongod --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard Legacy\mongod.cfg" --install*

**2. Service is correctly created, and if I copy the ImagePath of the service and paste to a console without the --service option, mongo runs fine.  ImagePath is:**

*"C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard Legacy\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard Legacy\mongod.cfg" --service*

**3. The service doesn't start, complaining with *Error 1054 - Service did not respond in Timely Fashion*.  In Windows event viewer I have no more information than that (no access errors, no other relevant info).**

---

**Other attemps with no success and same result (1054):**

- Even though ImagePath is correct (with quotes for blankspaces and full paths), I tried with a "C:\mongo" installation to avoid blankspaces.
- Tried putting quotes to paths in YAML file.
- As YAML is a new format, I tried with this config file

> ```
> port = 28019
> logpath = Z:\MongoDB\log\db02.log
> logappend = true
> dbpath = Z:\MongoDB\data\db02
> directoryperdb = true
> journal = true
> replSet = rs0
> quiet = false
> ```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue from version 2.6 onwards. A link in the docs explains how to create the service manually. I experienced the same issue, followed the documentation and it's now working:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#manually-create-windows-service